# Can get FullName from LDAP but not givenName or sn

Tags: vb.net, ldap

This works fine:

```
    Dim ADEntry = New DirectoryEntry(ldapPath + userName, au, ap)
    Dim Name = ADEntry.Properties("FullName").Value.ToString()
    Return Name
```

But this does not:

```
    Dim ADEntry = New DirectoryEntry(ldapPath + userName, au, ap)
    Dim firstName = ADEntry.Properties("givenName").Value.ToString()
    Dim lastName = ADEntry.Properties("sn").Value.ToString()
    Return firstName + " " + lastName
```

I also tried using ADEntry.Properties("givenName")(0).Value.ToString() as I read somewhere they may be indexed.  I got the same result, "Object reference not set to instance of an object".

Answer (score 2):

Those are indeed both indexed properties, and the way you're accessing them looks fine to me.

As a good practice though, you should check to make sure there is actually a value associated with this property before trying to read it - you can use a simple `.Contains` check :

```
If ADEntry.Properties.Contains("givenName") Then
```

If that evaluates to `false`, you'll know there's no value to read, thus you can avoid the object reference error you're receiving.

Also, you may want to look into using a `DirectorySearcher` to preload the properties you're interested in, instead of pathing directly to a `DirectoryEntry`. I'm a C# guy, but this page was very helpful when I was developing my LDAP components :

*Retrieving properties via `DirectorySearch` and `SearchResult`* (C#) http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have used a couple different accounts and have manually confirmed via Active Directory Users And Computers interface that they do have a First Name and Last Name listed.  I will try the "Contains" check, but regardless of whether it comes back true or false I still have some sort of issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I know this doesn't solve your question, but to get First Name and Last Name I had to use the following code:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string[] a = Context.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');


System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ADEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + a[0] + "/" + a[1]);
string FullName = ADEntry.Properties["FullName"].Value.ToString();
string FirstName = FullName.Substring(FullName.IndexOf(",") + 2);
string Lastname = FullName.Substring(0, FullName.IndexOf(","));
```

just in case it might be helpful to someone else